# Powerdns recursor returns unexpected SERVFAIL when forwarding to PowerDNS Authoritative

Tags: powerdns, powerdns-recursor

I have Powerdns recursor (4.4.2 from ubuntu repo) and PowerDNS Authoritative (4.4.1 from ubuntu repo) on the different servers.

Recursor config:

```
allow-from-file=/etc/pwrdnsallowfrom.acl
any-to-tcp=yes
forward-zones-file=/etc/pwrdnsforwaders.conf
log-common-errors=yes
log-timestamp=yes
new-domain-log=yes
unique-response-log=yes
loglevel=3
logging-facility=0
disable-syslog=no
max-negative-ttl=1
```

/etc/pwrdnsforwaders.conf content:

```
cat /etc/pwrdnsforwaders.conf
.=192.168.60.10
```

Authoritative config:

```
gmysql-host=localhost
gmysql-port=3306
gmysql-user=powerdns
gmysql-password=password
gmysql-dbname=powerdns
gmysql-dnssec
local-address=192.168.60.10
api=yes
api-key=apikey
allow-axfr-ips=127.0.0.1
allow-dnsupdate-from=127.0.0.1
allow-notify-from=127.0.0.1
disable-axfr=yes
any-to-tcp=yes
cache-ttl=60
master=yes
max-tcp-connections=20
non-local-bind=no
```

Sometimes the recursor will return a SERVFAIL in response to an nslookup request over and over again. Only restart helps:

```
systemctl restart pdns-recursor.service
```

When there is a problem, there is nothing out of the ordinary in the recursor logs:

```
Mar 18 09:09:54 pwrdnsrec pdns_recursor [5524]: 2 [1888/1] question for 'example.com | A' from 11.22.33.44:39530
Mar 18 09:09:54 pwrdnsrec pdns_recursor [5524]: 2 [1888/1] answer to non-rd question 'example.com | A': 1 answers, 0 additional, took 0 packets, 0 netw ms, 0 tot ms , 0 throttled, 0 timeouts, 0 tcp connections, rcode = 0
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

These were networking issues between recursor and authority. It is solved by adding to the recursor config:

```
  network timeout: 5000
```